# Usage for “rule set ” on mobile browser add-on

Tags: mobile

okay so I’m new to using tor and so far I love it! Was just curious what all of this was stored for? This picture looks harmless but once I scrolled down I noticed it’s basically every footprint I’ve left online.. there was more porn sites than I’m proud of ‍♀️ just curious about the process of all of this. Thanks for any response![image][image]

Comment: I think you forgot to include the image.

Comment: Thanks! I tried when I posted, but it should be up now! I’m just a little iffy like it has my amazon purchases also included.. I only use tor to look into the dark web out of curiosity. For my personal use I just put my browser in private mode. I just want to be sure my information isn’t shared somehow. But i mean if someone were to try please take my student loans lol. Just set me back a little when I saw.

Comment: This doesn't look like Tor Browser or is your question about another app?

Answer (score 1):

The list shown in your screenshot is not a list of every site you've visited.  Instead, it's a list of patterns that match URLs known to be used for serving ads and tracking you online.  Any URL which matches one of the listed patterns will be blocked from loading, which, as the caption at the top of the list says, increases your security and privacy, and reduces data usage.